# Flickering side-bars on Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

With the recent changes here, I've noticed something strange on the meta site.  Whenever I scroll, the side bars flicker.  It's a little distracting, and I was curious if others were having this problem, or if anyone had even noticed it yet.  This doesn't happen on the main site.

Comment: I was confused as to what you meant by sidebars; you mean the dark-gray background, right? Not the stuff with the related Questions and community bulletins and what not? I can reproduce this on Chrome Dev in Windows.

Comment: Also, I think it does happen on the main site, it's just not nearly as apparent.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  I mean the gray background, which I guess only has visible flickering on the side.  Also, I see it happening in both Chrome and IE9.

Comment: Do you have smooth scrolling turned on?  Oh wait, never mind.  It's just not as noticeable (or seizure inducing) with it off compared to on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be vsync issue.

Applying `background-attachment:fixed` to the `body` tag with the background should resolve this issue.

Comment: You're doing the Lord's work, sir. This fixes the bug. The change will be in the next prod build.